# How to pipe image to gstreamer using omxh264enc on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am piping images to gstreamer for encoding it to video using omxh264. In my code, the images are received from a source and piped to gstreamer. To replicate the issue, I extracted some frames in a directory and tried to pipe the images to gstreamer using the following command.

```
cat Images/* |gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc fd=0 ! videoparse framerate=25 ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! qtmux ! filesink location=out.mp4
```

However, i am getting the following messages (after setting GST_DEBUG="*:3")

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.136206216 14317  0x1ee58a0 WARN                GST_POLL gstpoll.c:829:gst_poll_remove_fd: 0x1edf450: couldn't find fd !
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
0:00:00.171278212 14317  0x1ec0c90 FIXME           videoencoder gstvideoencoder.c:606:gst_video_encoder_setcaps:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> GstVideoEncoder::reset() is deprecated
0:00:00.181177600 14317 0x72302120 WARN                GST_PADS gstpad.c:4092:gst_pad_peer_query:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0:src> could not send sticky events
0:00:00.183710793 14317 0x72302120 ERROR                    omx gstomx.c:2098:gst_omx_port_populate_unlocked:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> Failed to pass buffer 0x71900d50 (0x71804010) to video_encode port 201: Bad port index (0x8000101b)
0:00:00.184424533 14317 0x72302120 WARN             omxvideoenc gstomxvideoenc.c:945:gst_omx_video_enc_loop:<omxh264enc-omxh264enc0> error: Unable to reconfigure output port
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Enc-omxh264enc:omxh264enc-omxh264enc0: Could not configure supporting library.
Additional debug info:
gstomxvideoenc.c(945): gst_omx_video_enc_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Enc-omxh264enc:omxh264enc-omxh264enc0:
Unable to reconfigure output port
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
0:00:00.185111606 14317 0x72302120 FIXME               basesink gstbasesink.c:3126:gst_base_sink_default_event:<filesink0> stream-start event without group-id. Consider implementing group-id handling in the upstream elements
Freeing pipeline ...
```

If I replace the *omxh264enc* with *x264enc*, the command works fine. What am i doing wrong with the omxh264enc?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (was working on getting a bunch of images into an H264 video on RPI). Assuming the photos are in a folder and named Image001.jpg, Image002.jpg ect. This will covert the images to an avi file with 30 fps and resolution 640 * 480. Runs on RPI zero, using omxh264enc (GPU hardware accelerated)

Try:

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -e multifilesrc location="/Folder/Image%03d.jpg" !  
 image/jpeg, framerate=30/1 ! decodebin ! video/x-raw, width=640,  
 height=480 ! progressreport name=progress ! omxh264encode   
 target-bitrate=7500000 control-rate=variable ! video/x-h264, profile=high !  
 h264parse ! filesink location="/home/pi/Desktop/NewVideo.avi"
```